# Ant build fails when layout changes?

Tags: java, android, xml, ant

I generate my Android projects with *android create project*, and it creates a default template for layout. I use ant to build (debug) my project, but what I noticed is that it gives an error "build failed" whenever I change my main.xml layout file?

What could cause that?

The error ANT gives is this one:

> Path/To/Project/build:xml  The following error occured while executing this line: Path/To/Project/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

It only happens when I change the layout, has anyone encountered something similar?

Thank you for response in advance.

Comment: can you post the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use "android create project", I assume you are using an IDE, but you don't mention which one. If there's an option to "clean" your project, then try running this. This approach resolves issues at the command line and I assume it resolves similar issues when using an IDE.